# Trying to install Openmediavault on bananian linux 15.08r1 but facing problems

Tags: linux, debian, arm

For banana pie, bananian users, how have you managed to install openmediavault?
Here's what I tried:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
echo "deb http://packages.openmediavault.org/public kralizec main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openmediavault.list
wget -O - http://packages.openmediavault.org/public/archive.key | apt-key add -
apt-get update
apt-get install openmediavault-keyring postfix -y --force-yes
apt-get install php-apc openmediavault -y --force-yes
echo "deb http://packages.omv-extras.org/debian/ kralizec main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/omv-extras-org-kralizec.list
apt-get update
apt-get install openmediavault-omvextrasorg -y --force-yes
```

and i get error:

root@banana ~ # apt-get install php-apc openmediavault -y --force-yes
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php-apc is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openmediavault : Depends: php5-pam but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: proftpd-mod-vroot but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: php5-proctitle but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I tried to install the missing packages separately but get his error

```
     apt-get install php5-proctitle                     :(
     Reading package lists... Done
     Building dependency tree       
     Reading state information... Done
     Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
     requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
     distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
     or been moved out of Incoming.
     The following information may help to resolve the situation:
```

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-proctitle : Depends: phpapi-20100525+lfs but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue. For anyone else having this problem, OMV  isn't compatible with bananian 15.08. To get it to work, you'd need to downgrade to bananian 15.04 Cheers!

Update: Latest version of bananian is 16.04. You have to upgrade to omv 3 in order to make it work with it. OMV 3 is still in development but very stable for my needs.